# Very simple question on proving the equality of two PDE's.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

`A short extract from a book of mine states that:`

> If $$\color{red}{A(x,y)\frac{\partial p}{\partial
>  x}+B(x,y)\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}=0\tag{A}}$$ where $p=p(x,y)$
>    and $A$ and $B$ are also functions of $x$ and $y$.
>
> Also $$\color{blue}{\rm d p=\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\rm d
>  x+\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}\rm d y=0\tag{B}}$$
>   The forms of $\color{red}{(\rm A)}$ and $\color{blue}{(\rm B)}$ are
>   very alike and become the same if we require that
>   $$\color{#180}{\frac{\rm d x}{A(x,y)}=\frac{\rm d y}{B(x,y)}\tag{C}}$$ By integrating this expression the form of $p$ can be found.

I am trying to show that $\color{red}{(\rm A)}$ and $\color{blue}{(\rm B)}$ are the same; So I start by rearranging $\color{red}{(\rm A)}$ and $\color{blue}{(\rm B)}$ such that $$A(x,y)\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=-B(x,y)\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}\tag{D}$$ and $$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\rm d x=-\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}\rm d y\tag{E}$$ So ${(\rm E)}$ divided by ${(\rm D)}$ immediately recovers $\color{#180}{(\rm C)}$.

But how does this prove that $\color{red}{(\rm A)}$ and $\color{blue}{(\rm B)}$ are the same?

More importantly; Why does $\color{#180}{(\rm C)}$ ensure that $\color{red}{(\rm A)}$ and $\color{blue}{(\rm B)}$ are equal?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, (A) and (B) are not the same. Only if $\: p(x,y)=$constant when it is assumed that $dp=0$, the equation (C) is a part of the "characteristic equation" (see reference and link below).

This the base of the "method of characteristics" for solving first order linear PDE for example. This is well explained in : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Linear_and_quasilinear_cases

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate that.